# How wildcards works in Squid whitelisting configuration?

Tags: squid, whitelist

I'm a developer, not a sysadmin but I have the task to maintain a file which is basically a list of domains to whitelist. This file is used in the Squid caching proxy. The content of the file looks like this:

```
.example.com
.google.com
.bing.com
```

The file is used like this:

```
acl whitelist dstdomain "/path/to/squid/whitelist.txt"
```

Now I'm trying to find the documentation on how this file is parsed and I can't find clear (official) instructions on the Web on how to fill this file.

It seems that a dot before the domain will whitelist the domain and all it's subdomains. I'm trying to find if there is other wildcard rules that we can apply (like google.* or something like that).

I want to understand how it works not just follow blindly how we used this in the past.

Comment: Been many moons since I worked with it, but with the example you show it is .google.com allows http://google.com but not http://notgoogle.com whereas just google.com would allow anythinggoogle.com - note the lack of a . before the google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wildcards other than leading dot (.) are not supported in Squid's dstdomain acl. See http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl#How_do_I_implement_an_ACL_ban_list.3F